# JSON forEach get Key and Value

Tags: javascript, foreach

I have the following `forEach` loop over a JSON object called `obj`:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(){});
```

How can I make it `console.log` both `key` and `value` of each item inside the object?

Something like this:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k, v){
    console.log(k + ' - ' + v);
});
```

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Use index notation with the key.

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k){
    console.log(k + ' - ' + obj[k]);
});
```

Answer (score 25):

Loop through object with [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

**ES6**

```
Object.keys(myObj).forEach(key => {
    console.log(key + ' - ' + myObj[key]) // key - value
})
```

**ES7**

```
Object.entries(myObj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    console.log(key + ' - ' + value) // key - value
})
```

Comment: Object.entries is best answer if you have ES7+.   thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Another easy way to do this is by using the following syntax to iterate through the object, keeping access to the key and value:

```
for(var key in object){
  console.log(key + ' - ' + object[key])
}
```

so for yours:

```
for(var key in obj){
  console.log(key + ' - ' + obj[key])
}
```

Comment: In this case, using `hasOwnProperty` _is_ necessary, because the for...in construction includes properties inherited via the prototype chain.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that `obj` is a pre-constructed object (and not a JSON string), you can achieve this with the following:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){
   console.log(key + '=' + obj[key]);
});
```

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` isn't necessary because `Object.keys` already only includes own properties.  ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys))

Comment: Doenst Object.keys() ensures that only properties from the object itself are accessed? So no need for hasOwnProperty?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
var prop;
for(prop in obj) {
    if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;

    console.log(prop + " - "+ obj[prop]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) in combo with [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).

```js
const WALLPAPERS = [{
  WALLPAPER_KEY: 'wallpaper.image',
  WALLPAPER_VALID_KEY: 'wallpaper.image.valid',
}, {
  WALLPAPER_KEY: 'lockscreen.image',
  WALLPAPER_VALID_KEY: 'lockscreen.image.valid',
}];

WALLPAPERS.forEach((obj) => {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    console.log(`${key} - ${value}`);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way. **Assuming** I have a **JSON** of movies ...

```
movies.forEach((obj) => {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    console.log(`${key} ${value}`);
  });
});
```